# (Geometric and arithmetic mean)How to prove the function $G(x)-\alpha A(x)$ is concave?

Tags: convex-optimization

The geometric and arithmetic means of $x\in R^n_+$ are, respectively,
$$G(x)=(\prod^n_{i=1}x_i)^{1/n},\quad A(x)=\frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{i=1}x_i$$
Suppose $0\leq \alpha\leq 1$, how to prove the function $G(x)-\alpha A(x)$ is concave?
I try to solve it by Hessian matrix, but it seems not work.

Comment: The geometric mean is not that you defined...

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake.

Comment: Seems quite easy. The geometric mean is concave. Any linear function, including $-\alpha A(x)$ is concave. A sum of concave functions is concave.
Am I missing something?

Comment: @AlexShtof Yeah，you are right. Thankssss! (I'm so stupid)